python mysql connector gives incorrect result
This python code:
import mysql.connector

try:
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost", user="fanw", password="secret", database="fanw"
    )

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = """
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_pairs AS

        SELECT
            fd.nid,
            fd.title
        FROM
            node__field_card_display cl
        JOIN 
            node_field_data fd ON cl.entity_id = fd.nid AND cl.langcode = fd.langcode
        WHERE
            cl.field_card_display_target_id = 2049
            AND cl.langcode = 'en'
            AND cl.bundle = 'person';

        SELECT
            t.entity_id,
            t.deleted,
            t.delta,
            t.langcode,
            t.body_value,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tp.nid SEPARATOR ',') AS nids,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tp.title SEPARATOR ',') AS titles
        FROM
            node__body AS t
        JOIN
            temp_pairs AS tp ON BINARY t.body_value LIKE CONCAT('%', tp.title, '%') 
            AND NOT (t.body_value LIKE CONCAT('%', tp.nid, '">', tp.title, '<', '%'))
        WHERE
            t.body_format <> 'plain_text'
            AND t.entity_id <> tp.nid
        GROUP BY
            t.entity_id, t.langcode;
    """
    cursor.execute(query, multi=True)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(len(result))
    conn.commit()

except Exception as e:
    # Handle any errors and potentially roll back the transaction
    conn.rollback()
    print(f"Error: {str(e)}")

finally:
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

print("DONE!")

Gives the result: 0
While running the same query directly in mysql gives: 51
$ cat python_query.sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_pairs AS

SELECT
    fd.nid,
    fd.title
FROM
    node__field_card_display cl
JOIN 
    node_field_data fd ON cl.entity_id = fd.nid AND cl.langcode = fd.langcode
WHERE
    cl.field_card_display_target_id = 2049
    AND cl.langcode = 'en'
    AND cl.bundle = 'person';

SELECT
    t.entity_id,
    t.deleted,
    t.delta,
    t.langcode,
    t.body_value,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tp.nid SEPARATOR ',') AS nids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tp.title SEPARATOR ',') AS titles
FROM
    node__body AS t
JOIN
    temp_pairs AS tp ON BINARY t.body_value LIKE CONCAT('%', tp.title, '%') 
    AND NOT (t.body_value LIKE CONCAT('%', tp.nid, '">', tp.title, '<', '%'))
WHERE
    t.body_format <> 'plain_text'
    AND t.entity_id <> tp.nid
GROUP BY
    t.entity_id, t.langcode;

$ mysql -u fanw -p fanw < python_query.sql | wc -l
Enter password:
52

First row are the column names, hence 52 instead of 51.
$ pip freeze | grep mysql
mysql-connector-python==8.3.0

I've also tried a different library (PyMySQL), but it also gives 0.
Python version is 3.9.10 and I'm running this on a MacBook Pro M1 (12.7).
I've also run the query using DBeaver, and it gives the correct result: 51
I've tried two different libraries and I've tried two different other sources (DBeaver and the mysql client). Python libs both give the wrong result, and the DBeaver and mysql gives the expected and correct result.
I should also mention that I'm running this in a (python) virtual environment:
$ pip freeze
mysql-connector-python==8.3.0
PyMySQL==1.1.0

What am I doing wrong here?

Is the python code in the virtual env somehow connecting to a different database instance?

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_pairs - maybe you should drop the table first?

What if you add this cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TEMPORARY) before result = cursor.fetchall() does it works?

@JohnGordon Highly unlikely, I'm connecting to the instance via an SSH tunnel to a remote VM. It's the only instance running on that machine.
The same tunnel that DBeaver connects to.

@ScaryWombat Added DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_pairs; before CREATE TEMPORARY... both without and with a commit between - no difference.

@MosheEichler Maybe I misunderstood your instruction, but this:
cursor.execute(query, multi=True) cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM temp_pairs;")  result = cursor.fetchall() print(len(result))
Gives me the error: Error: 1146 (42S02): Table 'fanw.temp_pairs' doesn't exist

This was simply a case of RTFM.
When using multi=True in the execute-function, it returns an iterator:
    for each in cursor.execute(query, multi=True):
        result = each.fetchall()
        print(len(result))

So when I only did cursor.fetchall() it returned the result from the first query where the result of the SELECT likely is swallowed by the CREATE TEMPORARY ... AS.
The second iteration returns 51, as expected.
